# c# regex extracting substrings from a string

Tags: c#, regex

I need to get all substrings that are placed between 2 signs.

For example substrings placed between `]` and `[`:

```
abcabc]substrings[kkkkkkk]iwant[12345]tohave[!@#$%]
```

and I get: `substrings iwant tohave`

I tried `(?<=\])(.*)(?=\[)` but it returns `substrings[kkkkkkk]iwant[12345]tohave`.

Comment: Make it non-greedy `.*?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex would need to be `(?<=\])(.*`**`?`**`)(?=\[)`.

Note the added `?` sign to *match as few as possible*.

Then you have to combine the (at the moment) three matches with spaces and you will get the output you want!

Comment: its working, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Make it [non greedy](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `.*?` or else it would match until the last `[`

You don't need the [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) if you want to get the matches only:

[`(?<=\]).*?(?=\[)`](https://regex101.com/r/sUkL7d/1matc)

[Test](http://rextester.com/BDRFM90115)